# Angular 9 Reactive Forms: checkbox not getting updated when using trackBy

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am building the Products form using *reactive forms*.

When I select all the checkboxes and click reset, the checkboxes are not getting updated**

When I remove trackBy it is working fine, how can I make this work using `ngFor trackBy`?

here is the example : [stackblitz Products Form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ed26wx?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are returning index in `trackBy` function, the first argument of `trackBy` function is index of the item and second is the item itself you suppose to return the second argument.

In your example it would look like something.

P.S I renamed trackBy function with a generic name.

```
 trackByFn(_, item){
  return item;
 }
```

I forked your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o4q3td?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) you can check that out as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `trackByFn` function is not correct.

> The `trackBy` function takes the **index** and the **current item** as arguments
> and needs to return the **unique identifier** for this item.

So, try this:

```js
trackByFn(index, item){
  return index;
}
```

You can check the bug fixed version here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkfs33?file=src/app/app.component.ts).